# get pairs of string from a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want from this string :

`'Paris , Bruxelles , Amsterdam , Berlin'`

Get this result in an array :

`['Paris_Bruxelles' , 'Bruxelles_Amsterdam' , 'Amsterdam_Berlin' ]`

Can anyone help me please  ?

Comment: could you say the algorithm to merge strings?

Comment: Have you tried to solve this in some way? if yes, please paste your code, so the community can help you out, and get some feedback about what is wrong. Hint: what about using "Paris , Bruxelles , Amsterdam , Berlin".split(",") and " Bruxelles ".trim()??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could split the string and slice the array and get the pairs.

```js
var string = 'Paris , Bruxelles , Amsterdam , Berlin',
    array = string.split(/\s*,\s*/),
    result = array.slice(1).map((s, i) => [array[i], s].join('_'));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically in functional languages you are expected to use a `zipWith` function, where the accepted answer mimics that in JS with side effects.

However you may also mimic Haskell's pattern matching in JS and come up with a recursive solution without any side effects

```js
var cities = "Paris , Bruxelles , Amsterdam , Berlin , Bayburt".split(/\s*,\s*/),
    pairs  = ([f,s,...rest]) => s == void 0 ? []
                                            : [f + "_" + s].concat(pairs([s,...rest]));

console.log(pairs(cities));
```